# Finding z-score of annual income relative to state average income in R

Tags: r, statistics, normalization

I am looking to calculate the z-score of annual income within a data frame of a lot of values. As average annual income differs by state, I was hoping to find the z-score using the standard deviation and average by state to then apply to the individual rows.

data$annual_inc is as integer and 
data$state is as 50 level factor

Many thanks!

Comment: `aggregate(data$annual_inc, by=list(data$state), FUN=mean)`    `aggregate(data$annual_inc, by=list(data$state), FUN=sd)`

Comment: How is your data frame structured?  One column for all incomes, another for state?

Comment: Right. One column for all incomes and another factor for state

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is of the following form:

```
annual_inc  state
(numeric)   (character)
x1          S1
x2          S2
etc.
```

Then you can use `dplyr` as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
z.score <- data %>%
   group_by(state) %>%
   mutate(annual_z = (annual_inc - mean(annual_inc))/sd(annual_inc))
```

You can also find the mean and sd per state with relative ease, using:

```
data %>%
   group_by(state) %>%
   summarize(sd = sd(annual_inc),
             mean = mean(anuual_inc))
```

If you have missing values just add `na.rm = T` to the `mean` and `sd` command or filter them out of the data first.

P.S. You can also do this in base R, but `dplyr` has a lot of other benefits which I don't get into.

Comment: very nice! Quick, slightly novice question. How may I replace the annual_inc with the z score within the data frame while keeping the order?

Comment: By "keeping the order" do you mean sorting? because the code I specified shouldn't change the order of the rows. However, you can always use `sort`, `arrange` or `order` if you want to control the order of row. Please clarify the question for a better answer (give an example of what it looks like and how you want it to look like).